# Token symbol doesn't change on adding properties on chain

Tags: polkadot-js, substrate-node-template

I was able to add some properties in substrate-node-template chain_spec.rs file. But instead of `XCAV` token symbol it gives `MXCAV`. Is this issue or I am doing something wrong. Any advice or reference link would help a lot. And also try to add `total_supply` with properties but doesn't work.

[image]

```rs
pub fn local_testnet_config() -> Result<ChainSpec, String> {
    let wasm_binary = WASM_BINARY.ok_or_else(|| "Development wasm not available".to_string())?;

    let mut properties = Properties::new();
    properties.insert("tokenSymbol".into(), "XCAV".into());
    properties.insert("tokenDecimals".into(), 12.into());
    properties.insert("ss58Format".into(), 42.into());

    Ok(ChainSpec::from_genesis(
        // Name
        "Local Testnet",
        // ID
        "local_testnet",
        ChainType::Local,
        move || {
            testnet_genesis(
                wasm_binary,
                // Initial PoA authorities
                vec![authority_keys_from_seed("Alice"), authority_keys_from_seed("Bob")],
                // Sudo account
                get_account_id_from_seed::<sr25519::Public>("Alice"),
                // Pre-funded accounts
                vec![
                    get_account_id_from_seed::<sr25519::Public>("Alice"),
                    get_account_id_from_seed::<sr25519::Public>("Bob"),
                    get_account_id_from_seed::<sr25519::Public>("Charlie"),
                    get_account_id_from_seed::<sr25519::Public>("Dave"),
                    get_account_id_from_seed::<sr25519::Public>("Eve"),
                    get_account_id_from_seed::<sr25519::Public>("Ferdie"),
                    get_account_id_from_seed::<sr25519::Public>("Alice//stash"),
                    get_account_id_from_seed::<sr25519::Public>("Bob//stash"),
                    get_account_id_from_seed::<sr25519::Public>("Charlie//stash"),
                    get_account_id_from_seed::<sr25519::Public>("Dave//stash"),
                    get_account_id_from_seed::<sr25519::Public>("Eve//stash"),
                    get_account_id_from_seed::<sr25519::Public>("Ferdie//stash"),
                ],
                true,
            )
        },
        // Bootnodes
        vec![],
        // Telemetry
        None,
        // Protocol ID
        None,
        // Properties
        None,
        Some(properties),
        // Extensions
        None,
    ))
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well... This question is pretty simple. (you might find it's a little bit stupid later, LOL)

`M` is the unit. `M` for million.

You can mint more tokens to that account.
And you will see `BXCAV`, which is billion.
Cheers!

Comment: sometimes I get `4.9517 P XCAV` or `4.9517 E XCAV` as well. What does P and E indicate?

Comment: I don't know much about `P` or `E`. But I think this question is solved, and that's another question. Your token symbol setting is working as expected.